# Дождаться результата POST-запроса, отправленного через объект XMLHttpRequest и вернуть его в качестве результата функции

Tags: javascript, post

Пытаюсь проделать это при помощи кода:

```
function decodeValue(table, field, value) {
    var result;
    var http = false;
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.abort();
    http.open("POST", "routines.php", true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onreadystatechange=function() { if (http.readyState == 4) { result = http.responseText; } }
    http.send(`function=decode&table=${table}&field=${field}&value=${value}`);
    while (result === undefined) {}
    return result;
}

document.getElementById('myP').innerHTML = decodeValue('items', 'work_status_td', 'idle');
```

Но такое впечатление, что цикл while не видит изменений переменной result и страница зависает. Как пофиксить?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, нет этот вопрос о другом, по крайней мере непонятно, читая те ответы, где в моём примере ставить async и await

Comment: Как говорил мой препод по матану - "Если прочитали и ничего не поняли, читайте еще раз. И еще раз. Повторять, пока не поймете."

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, в приведённом Вами примере var data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'); а у меня  http.onreadystatechange=function() { if (http.readyState == 4) { result = http.responseText; } }. Попробовал http.onreadystatechange = async function() { if (http.readyState == 4) { result = await http.responseText; } } - не работает. И самое главное непонятно, почему не подходит while (result === undefined) {}? Этот цикл что, не улавливает изменения переменной result?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, пожалуйста снимите дубликат, чтобы я смог ответить на свой вопрос

Comment: Дубликат устанавливал не только я, а сообщество. Лично я не вижу причины снимать дубликат, потому что в дубликате описывается способ решения вашей проблемы. Смысл дубликата в том, что бы не плодить одинаковые ответы, а использовать уже существующие.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в дубликате правильным ответом даже не пахнет. Я решил, и знаю, как исправить. А Вы не даёте мне правильно ответить на вопрос

Comment: Что я вам не даю? Повторяю еще раз. Дубликат может снять только сообщество. Нужно 5 голосов, что бы снять дубликат. Я не могу это сделать. Более того, в ответе дубликате содержиться ответ на ваш вопрос :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko В каком месте в дубликате написано "http.open("POST", "routines.php", false);", то есть поставить false вместо true? А именно это и есть правильный ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @Igor будьте добры, снимите дубликат, чтобы я мог ответить на вопрос. Дубликат не относится к теме данного вопроса и в нём не содержится ответа на мой вопрос

Comment: @Igor, ничоси, первый раз вижу чтобы ты закрыл как дубль :-)

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, _то есть поставить false вместо true?_ - Это очень плохое решение, вешающее UI, на время выполнения запроса. Лучше воспользоваться решениями из дубликата.

Comment: @Grundy на мой взгляд вопрос закрыт необоснованно. Дубликат не отражает конкретно данного случая, и более того, совершенно не содержит правильного ответа. У меня уже готов правильный ответ, проверенный на практике, но я не могу ответить на этот вопрос, т.к. он закрыт

Comment: @Grundy, в дубликате масса воды, если Вы предложите (после открытия) лучший вариант ответа ПРИМЕНИТЕЛЬНО ИМЕННО К ЭТОМУ КОДУ, поставлю Ваш ответ правильный

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, любой из вариантов в дубликате - лучше синхронного запроса. В дубликате есть конкретные примеры кода того, как нужно сделать.

Comment: @Grundy ОК, выберите любой из вариантов и исправьте вышеприведённый код данного вопроса с учётом выбранного Вами варианта - лично у меня это не получается

Comment: @PavelSumarokov, `var response = await fetch("routines.php", {method:'POST', body:\`function=decode&table=${table}&field=${field}&value=${value}\`}); document.getElementById('myP').innerHTML = await response.text()`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96520/discussion-between-grundy-and-pavel-sumarokov).